# Share video on facebook using react-native-fbsdk

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I tried to share a link, it works and shows the dialog with the link.
I tried to share a photo, it works and shows the dialog with the picture.
I tried to share an mp4 video, it doesn't work and ShareDialog.show returns null without any other information.
I have used the following code to share a video on Facebook.

```
    const SHARE_VIDEO_CONTENT = {
    contentType: 'video',
    video: { localUrl: videoFilePath },
  }

shareVideoWithDialog = async () => {
    const canShow = await ShareDialog.canShow(SHARE_VIDEO_CONTENT);
    if (canShow) {
      try {
        const {isCancelled, postId} = await ShareDialog.show(
          SHARE_VIDEO_CONTENT,
        );
        if (isCancelled) {
          Alert.alert('Share cancelled');
        } else {
          Alert.alert('Share success with postId: ' + postId);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        Alert.alert('Share fail with error: ' + error);
      }
    }
  };
```